# Dividers in LinearLayout on android 4.0.3. HTC

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Only last divider is visible. Middle and first are invisible. ON samsung sIII 4.3 and LG optimus G anything is fine.

I was trying to set divider programmatically, but sill visible only last

```
LinearLayoutBuyTypes.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE | LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_BEGINNING | LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_END);
```

In xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutBuyTypes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/color_main_background"
                        android:divider="@drawable/delimiter_smooth_text_list_view"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
                         >
</LinearLayout>
```

What can I do to show middle and first dividers ?

Comment: A have HTC Incredible S sell phone with Android 4.0.3 and I also have this issue with dividers. Some times they are showing , sometimes not. Sometimes custom divider stay on screen when you switch the fragment. This is device issue.

Comment: How can i see, the 100% working way is to create view with background ... But is it not so correct ... May be any one have an answer ?..